# Unzip the specific folder in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, subdirectory, unzip

Is there any way I can unzip the specific folder from the zip file via NodeJS.

I tried this

```
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip') // Your zip file
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    const fileName = entry.path;
    const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    // file_name1, file_name1 are files which you are looking for
    if (type === 'File' && ['file_name1', 'file_name1'].indexOf(fileName) >= 0) {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path/' + fileName)); // Output folder of unzip process
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
 });
```

But this work only for files. I want to look for specifc folder and unzip that.

Comment: What does "look for specific folder" mean?  Are you looking on the hard drive for a specific folder?  Are you looking in the zip file for a specific folder?

Comment: I want to exclude root directory inside zip if it contains the root directory otherwise ignore that

Answer (score -1):

```
var filename = req.files[0].filenam
var zippath = __dirname + "../../../../../public/uploads/pages/zip/"
var unzippath = __dirname + "../../../../../public/uploads/pages/"
fs.createReadStream(zippath + filename).pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: unzippath }))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.